# Problem installing LibreOffice on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: libreoffice, amazon-linux

I am following the instructions on how to install LibreOffice on Fedora which is what I believe Amazon Linux 2023 uses under the hood:

https://tecadmin.net/install-libreoffice-on-fedora/

I can download and extract the zip package. However, when I run `dnf install RPMS/*.rpm`, I get the following error:

```
error: No package matches 'RPMS/libobasis7.6-base-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm'
```

The content of the RPMS folder is as follows:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1237800 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-base-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  7643097 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-calc-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 91309240 Dec  1 10:54 libobasis7.6-core-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     6407 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-draw-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    81581 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-en-US-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   404419 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-extension-beanshell-script-provider-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   642636 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-extension-javascript-script-provider-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1998248 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-extension-mediawiki-publisher-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1067433 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-extension-nlpsolver-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3329870 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-extension-pdf-import-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2971346 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-extension-report-builder-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2959808 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-firebird-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   610717 Dec  1 10:54 libobasis7.6-gnome-integration-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1222506 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-graphicfilter-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 61644927 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-images-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   191522 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-impress-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2340064 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-kde-integration-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   208326 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-librelogo-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     3718 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-libreofficekit-data-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   538291 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-math-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   157039 Dec  1 10:52 libobasis7.6-ogltrans-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   125283 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-onlineupdate-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 17292382 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-ooofonts-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2757 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-ooolinguistic-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2025230 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-postgresql-sdbc-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    13292 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-python-script-provider-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  9795742 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-pyuno-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  3952315 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-writer-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   420612 Dec  1 10:51 libobasis7.6-xsltfilter-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   576247 Dec  1 10:52 libreoffice7.6-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2347 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-base-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2343 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-calc-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  5682300 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-dict-en-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2780003 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-dict-es-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  1857501 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-dict-fr-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2347 Dec  1 10:51 libreoffice7.6-draw-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     7518 Dec  1 10:52 libreoffice7.6-en-US-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   752859 Dec  1 09:09 libreoffice7.6-freedesktop-menus-7.6.4-1.noarch.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2382 Dec  1 10:54 libreoffice7.6-impress-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2347 Dec  1 10:52 libreoffice7.6-math-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 14441942 Dec  1 10:52 libreoffice7.6-ure-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root     2369 Dec  1 10:54 libreoffice7.6-writer-7.6.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm
```

It appears that the missing file is actually there, but I can't install LibreOffice.

This is my dockerfile, and I am executing this on an Apple M3 Macbook:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

RUN dnf install \
    gzip \
    wget \
    tar \
    -y && \
    dnf clean all

RUN wget https://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/stable/7.6.4/rpm/x86_64/LibreOffice_7.6.4_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf LibreOffice_7.6.4_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz
RUN cd LibreOffice_7.6.4.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm/
RUN dnf install RPMS/*.rpm
```

Comment: Try adding -v (for more verbose output).

Answer (score 0):

More information such as the commands you are running and the full error you get from those commands would be helpful.  Though I think I know what your problem may be.

Each `RUN` command in a Dockerfile is a different shell session, so your `cd` would not carry into the next session and you would be placed back into the working directory.

Try combining the two commands into one `RUN` statement:

```
RUN cd LibreOffice_7.6.4.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm/ && dnf install RPMS/*.rpm
```

or don't use `cd` at all:

```
RUN dnf install LibreOffice_7.6.4.1_Linux_x86-64_rpm/RPMS/*.rpm
```